# How to set kiosk using windows imaging and configuration designer

Tags: windows, kiosk

I am going to set kiosk setting using Windows Configuration Designer.

I followed this [Set up a kiosk using the kiosk wizard in Windows Configuration Designer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app#wizard).

But when i set app type to Classic Windows App, black screen is showed and classic app is not started.
And when i set app type to Universal Windows App, all windows is showed not only uwp app.

What's the problem.

My OS is Windows 10 Pro 20H2 Build 19042.630.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a new user and I was trying to get my reputation up to 50 so I could comment and work with you, rather than answer your question, since I didn't have an answer yet, but I just discovered a solution that worked for me. I think this may be a bug in Windows, I had the exact same issue you mentioned, but here's what worked for me...

As I understand it, setting a Classic Windows App replaces the Explorer.exe from loading after logging in and instead loads the app you specify, at least in theory, but it just never loads. When you get to that "black screen" you can Ctrl+Shift+Esc or Ctrl+Alt+Del and then open up task manager, then you can File, Run new task, to run commands or just type `explorer` and click OK to load the normal desktop.

To get your Classic Windows App to open as expected for the Kiosk, open Task Scheduler, Create Basic Task..., Name it, Next, Set the trigger to When I log on, Set the Action to Start a Program (default), Browse for and select your Classic Windows App, Next, Finish. When done the important thing to check is that the Trigger shows `At log on of [whatever your Kiosk user account is]` under Details. If not, you can edit it.

As an additional security measure, you'll probably want to set a policy to [disable Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/318817/disable-task-manager-for-restricted-user-on-windows-7-home-premium) so savvy users don't use the trick to load the desktop as I mentioned above. The above link says Win7, but it's the same process for Win10. Be sure you only apply it to the Kiosk account, you don't want to block the admin account from loading Task Manager. Users would still be able to Ctrl+Alt+Del and access those, Lock, Switch User, Sign Out, and Change a password options, but those all have far less potential for damaging your Kiosk. If you ever need to make changes you can Ctrl+Alt+Del to switch to your admin account then use the above trick to get the desktop loaded. You can lock it down even more with more policies, but that's a separate topic.

Good Luck!